# Checksum error on running tlmgr

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, tlmgr

I installed TexLive on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine:

```bash
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

Now, when I try to update it, I get an error:

```bash
~$ tlmgr update --self --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

Any idea what's wrong?